# show only sub categories if available?

Tags: categories, archives, customization

Hii i want that when i click on category link that show sub category if available instead of posts list
If No Sub category available then show normal posts
how to do this that if available sub categories only show just sub categories not any other posts
Mean which extra code i add in my archive page that show sub categories if available otherwise show posts
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a conditional statement, for example:

```
$sub_cats = get_categories('parent='.get_query_var('cat'));
if( $sub_cats ) : 
//show list of child categories, for instance with wp_list_categories()
 echo '<ul>;
 wp_list_categories('title_li=&child_of='.get_query_var('cat'));
 echo '</ul>';
//or possibly using $sub_cats and a foreach loop//
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach( $sub_cats as $sub_cat ) {
   echo '<li><a href="'.get_category_link($sub_cat->term_id).'">'.$sub_cat->name.'</a></li>'; 
  }
 echo '</ul>';
else:
//the 'normal' LOOP of category.php//
endif;
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

edit: list code for sub categories added

Comment: Well after applying method that is not showing sub categories that is showing array how to get sub categories in list instaed of showing array ?

Comment: you could use `wp_list_categories()` with the 'child_of' parameter;  or use a foreach loop with the result of $sub_cats; I edited my answer to include both possibilities.